# Cross product in uneven matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, cross-product

[image]

I don't need help with dot product, only the cross product section. Even a hint as to where to start would be great.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) is if you think it's defined for square matrices.

Comment: Well, I need to solve this one, and I haven't had to since one physics course about 6 years ago, so maybe I'm a bit foggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remember these rules:  For the standard basis vectors $i$, $j$, and $k$, and for *any* vectors $\vec v$, $\vec u$, and $\vec w$ and *any* real number $c$, we have
$$\begin{array}\ 1)\ i\times j = k & j\times k = i & k\times i = j\end{array} \\ \begin{array}\ 2)\ \vec v\times \vec u = -\vec u\times \vec v\end{array} \\ \begin{array}\ 3)\ \vec v \times \vec v = 0\end{array} \\ \begin{array}\ 4)\ \vec v\times (\vec u+\vec w) = \vec v\times \vec u + \vec v\times \vec w\end{array} \\ \begin{array}\ 5)\ (c\vec v)\times \vec w = \vec v\times (c\vec w) = c(\vec v\times \vec w) \end{array}$$

Then write out your two vectors in terms of $i$, $j$, and $k$: $A = 2i + j + 3k$ and $B = -i + 2j + 3k$.  Then just use your rules:

$$A \times B = (2i + j + 3k)\times (-i + 2j + 3k)$$ $$= -2i\times i +4i\times j +6i\times k -j\times i +2j\times j +3j\times k -3k\times i +6k\times j + 9 k\times k$$ $$= (4+1)i\times j+(6+3)i \times k + (3-6)j\times k$$ $$= 5k -9j-3i$$

Thus the solution is $\begin{bmatrix} -3 \\ -9 \\ 5\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Thank you, the vectors being different sizes was throwing me, total brain fart to not convert the 2nd one to ijk like normal. Thank you.